# Testing in AngularJS : How do I test the backend response of my API's?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, protractor, karma-runner

I am new to testing in AngularJS and just started to use testing using Karma and jasmine for a particular use case. Actually, I am a front end developer and the backend API's keep changing as the system is under migration. So I wanted to implement a test on service wherein I can catch response from the actual API and test the response where I have the same data all the time as the database is exported and is in the consistent state. 
Is there a way to do it? Because all articles I have read they mock the response of the API and then test the individual methods written. Or do I have to use protractor for E2E testing?

Answer (score 3):

When you run tests with karma, your backend will be mocked as soon as you load angular-mocks.js (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). This is what we want because we need unit tests to run quickly without having to run a backend and database.

If you need to test the interaction between your app and the real API, you need to do E2E tests with protactor, as in this kind of test, the backend is running.

Now, if you need to test the real API output, it is - in my humble opinion - the work of the backend developer. Having that said, you can of course test it yourself, but it has nothing to do with AngularJS. I'm not a NodeJS developer but there are tools to test API endpoint. You can look at [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) for example wich

> provide a high-level abstraction for testing HTTP

Here is an example from their documentation :

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Comment: @MBielski I don't want to test if the API is calculating the output correctly... But if the parameters that we decided to send in the response are same plus the API endpoint is still the same and no change has been done to improve the endpoint's verbosity. That's all. We have tests in Mocha in the NodeJS backend to test each and every function being called from that end point.

Comment: @MBielski you're right, I corrected my answer. Thank you for your point

Comment: @SarasArya you don't need your angular app in order to check your API contract. You can perfectly test your nodeJs endopint with mocha using SuperTest or Chai for example.

Comment: Comment deleted, and then thought about it and realized that then your followup comment made no sense without it. OC was that Karma does not mock out your back end if you do not load angular-mocks.

Answer (score 1):

Many people forget that Karma is not specific to Angular. It is made to run tests on JavaScript code, regardless of the framework you may or may not use. So, you can run tests with Karma that do not use Angular or Angular Mocks and that interact with a database. These types of tests are called integration or functional tests (there's a fine line that separates the two, depending upon how you look at it) and they should be included in every project. I have seen tests of this nature use Jasmine, and I have seen them use Mocha. The choice is yours. Either way, don't expect them to run as fast as unit tests since you'll be contending with network and database latency. When you run these tests in your development cycle is up to you. Since they take longer, most times they are only run on a full build or after the API/database have changed.

All of this being said, the developers that produce the API should be the ones writing/running these tests and providing you (the customer) with updated documentation.

Comment: Can you point me to some resource which shows by an example on how to call a live API and then they assert the response?

Comment: Asking people to Google things for you is not how it's done here on SO. There are plenty of websites available for showing what you want. Keywords like 'Node mocha test api' should get you a reason able list.